# How do I merge database rows based on common values?

Tags: sql, database, merge, hiveql

I've got a table like this:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
====   ====   ====   ====   ====
 A1     B1     C1    null   null
 A1    null    C1    null    E1
 A1     B2    null    D1     E2
 A1    null    C2    null    E2
```

How do I merge the information so that I end up with:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
====   ====   ====   ====   ====
 A1     B1     C1    null    E1
 A1     B2     C2     D1     E2
```

What SQL will do this for me?  Notice the two C1's allow the first 2 rows to be merged, and the two E2's allow the last 2 rows to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps..

```
CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTable(
col1 varchar(50) ,
col2 varchar(50) NuLL, 
col3 varchar(50) NuLL,
col4 varchar(50) NuLL, 
col5 varchar(50) NuLL)

insert into #LocalTempTable values ( 'A1', 'B1','C1',NULL,NULL);
insert into #LocalTempTable values ( 'A1', NULL,'C2',NULL,'E1');
insert into #LocalTempTable values ( 'A1', 'B2',NULL,'D1','E2');
insert into #LocalTempTable values ( 'A1', NULL,'C2',NULL,'E2');


select * from #LocalTempTable


 --A1     B1     C1    null    E1
 --A1     B2     C2     D1     E2
 select  *from(
select  ROW_NUMBER() over  ( order by lc1.col1  ) as ID ,
lc1.col1
,lc1.col2
,lc1.col3
,lc1.col4
,lc2.col5
 from #LocalTempTable lc1 inner join #LocalTempTable lc2 on lc2.col1=lc1.col1 ) as c where ID=5
 union 

 select  *from(
select  ROW_NUMBER() over  ( order by lc1.col1  ) as ID ,
lc1.col1
,isnull(lc1.col2,lc2.col2) as col2
,isnull(lc2.col3,lc1.col3) as col3
,isnull(lc1.col4,lc2.col4) as col4
,lc2.col5
 from #LocalTempTable lc1 inner join #LocalTempTable lc2 on lc2.col1=lc1.col1 ) as c where ID=10
```

Comment: Thanks Pandey, but I was wondering about the general case.  Your solution assumes the precise data I used as an example, e.g.: in the select after the union, you order the isnull parameters based on my example, and you write lc2.col5 without an isnull because you know col5 is not null for either of the last 2 rows.  What I'm looking for is a general query to merge information when one (or more) columns have the same data value.